# Wifi Regulatory Domain for Bohemia?

Tags: wireless

USA has reg domain 0x0 , but what is Reg. Domain Code for Bohemia? (BO)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- There is no code for Bohemia because **Bohemia is a not a country**, but a [historical region which is currently part of the Czech Republic.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohemia)
- `BO` is the two-letter ISO code [for **Bolivia**](http://www.iso.org/iso/support/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/iso-3166-1_decoding_table.htm#BO) (in South America)
- The ISO *country code* for Bolivia (BO) is [68](http://www.davros.org/misc/iso3166.html), which is `0x44` in hex.

  - There is no *regdomain* (regulatory domain) code for Bolivia; [that is a proprietary specification introduced by Atheros and most cards use the wildcard `0x00`](http://madwifi-project.org/wiki/UserDocs/CountryCode)

Comment: What is Hex code for Bolivia then?

Comment: @BigGenius , please see edits

Comment: Which is idea Reg domain, according to you? In terms of best Wifi Signal Reception? Highest Tx power?